# link for sharing an event to yahoo calendar

Tags: hyperlink, calendar, yahoo

I have been looking for a way to add events to my yahoo calendar through a link. So far I have found the following links:

[Adding Events to Users Calendars – Part 2 – Web Calendars](http://richmarr.wordpress.com/2008/01/07/adding-events-to-users-calendars-part-2-web-calendars/)

[Adding Calendar Events to Yahoo](http://armcnallie.wordpress.com/2008/03/12/adding-calendar-events-to-yahoo/)

[Yahoo! Calendar "Add Event" Seed URL Parameters](http://chris.photobooks.com/tests/calendar/Notes.html)

The problem I have is when an event has an end date that is more that 99hours 99min away from the start date  (say for example a year for the start date) as the format for the duration is HHmm. Anyone know how to specify the link for this type of an event?

Also does anyone know the format of the REND parameter (used for recurring events)?

Comment: There is a GitHub repository that includes yahoo parameters description: https://github.com/InteractionDesignFoundation/add-event-to-calendar-docs

Answer (score 3):

Now Yahoo has updated the parameter to be ET for 'end time'.

Use parameter ET with the YYYYMMDD format and the calendar event should display properly. (i.e. ET=20150119 for an end date of January 19th, 2015)

Comment: As of Oct 15, 2015, the `et` param appears to be broken with respect to UTC datetimes. If you pass something like `st=20151015T0900Z&et=20151015T1000Z` (9-10am UTC). Yahoo will properly set the start date to local user time, but the end date will remain in UTC. The only way to pass a datetime in UTC *and* have the correct end time is to use the `dur` param instead of `et`.

Comment: And dur can only cover up to 99 hours+99minutes from the start of the event. If your event spans multiple days but has a specific end time on the last day, it's going to be off by a certain # of hours.

I've tried in vain to figure out how to trigger the "all Day" checkbox from the url, but I've both been unable to and really decided I don't want to in multiday cases. Clicking that checkbox FORCES the end date to be one day after the start date, at 12:00am. Not desirable.

Comment: @Dtipson You can set the dur parameter to allday, like `dur=allday`. That will force Yahoo Calendar to initially check the all day box.

Answer (score 0):

According to a comment on http://armcnallie.wordpress.com/2008/03/12/adding-calendar-events-to-yahoo/ REND is YYYYMMDD format (the article itself claims it's the number of seconds since 1/1/1970, but if that was the case it no longer appears to work - YYYYMMDD does work for me).